# API for programmatically accessing mail in Python on mac os X

Tags: python, macos, api, email

i would like to programmatically access via python all the mail that exists on a Mac OS X system, which is received by the built in "Mail.app" program. are there friendly apis for accessing the mail as stored by that program? My impression is that it's not just a text format and that it might be more complicated. thanks.

Comment: Is this for a one-time export/conversion or do you want a program to check this regularly?  If the former, you can probable manually export your emails using the "Mail.app" program to a standard format, such as RFC822 and then parse that using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail.app stores messages as .emlx files, which is an undocumented format AFAIK. But you could convert .emlx files to the standard mbox format (using [this](https://www.recoverytools.com/emlx/mbox/)) and then process them with the [mailbox](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html) module.

Answer (score 11):

As of 2020, you can use the [Python emlx library](https://github.com/mikez/emlx).

```
pip install emlx
```

Example code:

```
import emlx
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob("/Users/<username>/Library/Mail/**/*.emlx", recursive=True):
     m = emlx.read(filepath)
```

On a message `m`, you can do various operations:

```
>>> m.headers
{'Subject': 'Re: Emlx library ✉️',
 'From': 'Michael <michael@example.com>',
 'Date': 'Thu, 30 Jan 2020 20:25:43 +0100',
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
 ...}
>>> m.headers['Subject']
'Re: Emlx library ✉️'
>>> m.plist
{'color': '000000',
 'conversation-id': 12345,
 'date-last-viewed': 1580423184,
 'flags': {...}
 ...}
>>> m.flags
{'read': True, 'answered': True, 'attachment_count': 2}
```

If you need **speed**, you can parse the `plist` and `flags` only:

```
>>> m = emlx.read(filepath, plist_only=True)
```

Comment: I guess the recursive option is there for reading folders. Doesn't work for me: 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/emlx/emlx.py", line 112, in read
    filebuffer = open(filepath_or_buffer, "rb")
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/javor/Library/Mail/'

Comment: @user3603644 I updated the glob. Thanks for catching.

Comment: Will any changes like moving a message sync back to the IMAP server (or exchange in my case)?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat This library is intended for reading Apple Mail emlx files, not for modifying the content of the IMAP server.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
fname = glob.glob('./mails/**/*.emlx', recursive = True)
    msg = emlx.read(fname)
    print(msg.headers['Subject'])
```

the /**/ in the path string acts as a wildcard

Comment: This is basically just Michael's answer, isn't it?